# how to pass pointer to a method as another method argument

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

All!

I have some class hierarchy

```
class A {public: virtual void foo(int, T*) = 0; virtual void foo1(int, T*) = 0;};
class B : public A {public: void foo(int, T*) override; void foo1(int, T*) override;};
class C : public B {public: void foo(int, T*) override; void foo1(int, T*) override;};
```

In client code

```
class D{void client_foo(A* pA, bool, T*);};
void D::client_foo(A* pA, bool b, T* pT)
{
    if (b) pA->foo(1050, pT);
    else pA->foo1(5010, pT);
}
```

I want to introduce new function `void D::client_helper(???)` which will achieve `pA`, int value, `pT` and pointer to method of `class A` to be called. 
So, `D::client_foo(...)` could be rewritten as:

```
void D::client_foo(A* pA, bool b, T* pT)
{
    if (b) client_helper(pA, 1050, pT, std::mem_fn(&A::foo));
    else client_helper(pA, 5010, pT, std::mem_fn(&A::foo1));
}
```

the question is: what signature should `D::client_helper()` have?

Comment: Why are your class definitions overly compacted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `std::function<ret_type(arg_1)>` and `std::bind` instead of `std::mem_fn`

e.g.

client function:

```
void client_helper(std::function<void (T*)> fnFoo, T* pT)
{
     nfFoo(pT);
}
```

call of the function:

```
usign namespace std::placeholders;
A* pA;
T* pT;
client_helper(std::bind(&A::foo, pA, 1050, _1), pT);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since both `A::foo` and `A::foo1` have the same signature, there's no need for `std::mem_fn`, or another abstraction, just have `client_helper` take a plain pointer to member function of `A`.

```
void client_helper(A* pA, int i, T* pT, void(A::*memfn)(int, T*))
{
    (pA->*memfn)(i, pT);
}
```

And call it as

```
void client_foo(A* pA, bool b, T* pT)
{
    if (b) client_helper(pA, 1050, pT, &A::foo);
    else client_helper(pA, 5010, pT, &A::foo1);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7277aeb102beea0)

Answer (score 2):

For passing functions as arguments, you have [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).